# glFlush() vs [[self openGLContext] flushBuffer] vs glFinish vs glSwapAPPLE vs aglSwapBuffers

Tags: cocoa, macos, opengl

There are several similar OpenGL operations when working with an NSOpenGLView:

- `glFlush()`
- `[[self openGLContext] flushBuffer]`
- `glFinish()`
- glSwapAPPLE
- aglSwapBuffers

When should each of these be used?

In a sample application, Apple uses `glFlush()`, followed by `[[self openGLContext] flushBuffer]`.  Why do they use both of these?

What would be the right approach, if I am using a double-buffered Cocoa NSOpenGLView?

Comment: Although I have no experience with Apple (therefore it's no answer), when using double buffering you should usually call something like a swapBuffers function. In this case a flush or finish function should not be neccessary, as the buffer swap should wait for the completion of all previous commands, anyway, or better it may even be asynchronous, so you can already do other work, without needing to wait for the commands to be finished (like `glFinish` does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_designstrategies/opengl_designstrategies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH2-SW8)? It explains when to use glFlush() and glFinish(). Both are OpenGL functions that control execution and synchronizing of commands. Generally you would want to use these functions when doing multi-threaded rendering otherwise there shouldn't be any need.

glSwapAPPLE() and aglSwapBuffers() are extensions provided by Apple to display the contents of the backbuffer to screen (on Windows it's wglSwapBuffers()). You should use either one but not both as they really do the same thing. I would stick to the AGL method as it's analogous to WGL, EGL, etc..

`[[self openGLContext] flushBuffer]` is probably an objective C wrapper to glFlush() from the looks of it. I can't imagine it doing anything else.

Comment: According to your link the `flushBuffer` method of the `NSOpenGLContext` class is actually doing a buffer swap (and a `glFlush` before) in double buffered mode. So this is actually the only function needed. And as he's working with the NS classes anyway, I would rather suggest to use this one instead of the other swapping functions.

Comment: `aglSwapBuffers` is part of the OpenGL API for Carbon apps, and therefore I don't think it should be used in a Cocoa app.

Answer (score 11):

Be careful! `[[self openGLContext] flushBuffer]` is not just an Objective-C wrapper for `gFlush()`. This function (`- (void)flushBuffer` in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenGLContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOpenGLContext/flushBuffer))  works only if you set double buffer in your pixel format like

```
NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attributes [] =
    {
        NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
        // other presets like
        // NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile, NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core,
        // NSOpenGLPFADepthSize, 32,
        0
    };

    NSOpenGLPixelFormat *pixelFormat = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] 
                                            initWithAttributes:attributes];
```

Otherwise you have to use `glFlush();` It took me a long time until I saw the essential line in the [NSOpenGLContext Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenGLContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOpenGLContext/flushBuffer).

Answer (score 2):

The correct approach is just calling `[[self openGLContext] flushBuffer]`.